# Symantec AntiVirus virus definitions file version date is not updating

Tags: anti-virus, update, symantec

I'm keeping tabs on a remote sever that is running Symantec AntiVirus Corporate Server 10.1.7.7001. About a month ago, the Virus Definition File version date stopped updating and hasn't updated since - 3/26/2012 rev. 2. The automatic update has continued to run everyday, downloading the latest definitions, but not updating the version date in the client.

I have run the LiveUpdate service manually. Sometimes it downloads an update successfully and other times it says the virus definitions are up to date. If I run it again after a successful download, it will always say it's up to date. I don't think it is an issue of getting the virus definition.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all - this site is really not a substitute for the Symantec's techsupport.
If you have a support contract with them - I really suggest you contact them instead.

If you don't, let's start the standard troubleshooting first:

1. Do you use SEPM?
2. Does the Server update through SEPM?
3. What update servers are you using?
4. Can you provide update logs? (Located in C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Symantec\Symantec AntiVirus Corporate Edition\%VERSION%\Logs)
5. Take a look at their basic troubleshooting guides:
   http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH105894&locale=en_US
   http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH95790&locale=en_US
   http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH95789